# SSH cannot login with root pasword

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a buildroot system that I cannot log in into with via `root`, with log in using `.ssh/authorized_keys` working, but isn't practical since it's a read-only filesystem.

How can I enable password-based login and can I enable logging of `sshd` to get more info?

- **`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:**

  ```ini
  Subsystem  sftp                   = /usr/libexec/sftp-server
  PermitRootLogin                   = yes
  PasswordAuthentication            = yes
  ChallengeResponseAuthentication   = yes
  ```
- **`/etc/passwd`:**

  ```bsh
  root:CD.Dnox5Dc2RQ:0:0:root:/home/root:/bin/sh
  daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/false
  bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/false
  sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/false
  sync:x:4:100:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
  mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/spool/mail:/bin/false
  www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/false
  operator:x:37:37:Operator:/var:/bin/false
  test:<hash>/:100:100:user:/home/test:/bin/sh
  nobody:x:99:99:nobody:/home:/bin/false
  sshd:x:1000:1000:SSH drop priv user:/:/bin/false
  ```
- **`ssh -v root@device`**

  ```bsh
  OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
  debug1: Connecting to device [192.168.10.202] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
  debug1: Authenticating to device:22 as 'root'
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
  debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
  debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

  debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:VY8wYy/5GDoAl39tVLWHtJcUaDFUfLR1/3hiTBbv+ww
          The authenticity of host 'device (192.168.10.202)' can not be established.
          ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:VY8wYy/5GDoAl39tVLWHtJcUaDFUfLR1/3hiTBbv+ww.
          Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
          Warning: Permanently added 'device,192.168.10.202' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

  debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:+pbphA33IlRNVBroM+DLokCIZII2eSzo095QDT16gNI /home/jenia/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/jenia/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/jenia/.ssh/id_ed25519
  debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive

  debug1: Next authentication method: password
          root@device password:

  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
          Permission denied, please try again.
  ```

Comment: Check the syslogs on meshit. Look for any log entries by `sshd` saying why the authentication attempt failed.

Comment: `root` should never have passwordless login for the obvious security reasons

Comment: @JW0914 disagree strongly. Key based authentication is way more secure then password based authentication for a start.  In some setups, machines performing the same role (eg hot backups, cluster nodes) may require passwordless login between them (using SSH keys with no passphrase) for root to sync. This can be worked around, but done correctly provides a robust environment if operating at a smallish scale.

Comment: @davidgo What exactly are you disagreeing with? 'root' login should always be via SSH only, password login disabled, and the key should be encrypted with a passphrase.

Comment: @JW0914 We are closer to agreement - I understand "never have passwordless login"  to mean that logins should require a password.   I still disagree that ssh logins always need a password or passphrase where they are set up between peers to facilitate automated management which can require arbitrary commands run as root which may be under the control of an automated script/system - one example could be for file system  backups - provided appropriate protections are in place for the backup server and the backup server is logging in to the client.

Comment: @davidgo Best practice is to always encrypt SSH keys unless appropriate protections have been enacted for automation, however this question wasn't about automation and in the context of the author's question, root login should not be passwordless _(passwordless is used in the context of the SSH config, as passwordless in an SSH config means SSH keys only)_.

Comment: @JW0914 I am sure we are in agreement in reality, but are disagreeing on the meaning of words.  (Giving you that Passwordless implies key based authentication then root logins should always be passwordless as a matter of best practice.  That key should normally be protected by a passphrase.  This doesn't help the author).